# print generator object value instead of generator itself

Tags: python

I am trying to print everything from an excel spreadsheet using `openpyxl`.

When I perform the following code:

```
csvdata = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'data.xlsx')
print(csvdata['Sheet'].values)
```

I get a return value of this:
`[<generator object Worksheet.values at 0x7f4f090a52e0>]`

how can I get the actual value instead of the reference? I tried adding `()` to values but the interpreter said that values is not callable.

Comment: `print(list(csvdata['Sheet'].values))`?

Comment: `values` is a generator; you have to *iterate* over it to get the data it will yield.

Comment: @chepner I understand that values is a generator but I only know how to use a generator concept with a for loop if that makes sense. I assumed that this generator was some sort of variable where if I add it onto `csvdata['sheet']` it would do the for loop for me. @dumbPotato - I will try your idea in a couple of seconds and reply again.

Comment: Oh that is cool! @dumbPotato21 I didn't know you can just build a list with using `list`. I didn't know that `list` is a module on its own (it turned green in vscode). If you want, you can make an answer and I will give you credit. Thanks again

Comment: `list` is a type, not a module. When called, it takes an arbitrary iterable value and produces a new instance of `list` containing the values read from the iterable.